# YouTube API V3 recordingDetails object missing in the response

Tags: youtube-api

I have tried this YouTube API v3 call from curl today:

http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ZCJgvabihQ8&key=apiKey&part=snippet,recordingDetails

Everything else is fine, but I didn't find the recordingDetails object in the response json:

```
{
"kind":"youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag":"\"oLweQuB9Vh7wAB9a0AIHg_K-wsM/EuRsJ-sxI3qstP1T58S5Qnb_NIg\"",
"items":[
{
    "id":"ZCJgvabihQ8",
    "kind":"youtube#video",
    "etag":"\"oLweQuB9Vh7wAB9a0AIHg_K-wsM/CYNTRL05S4okPzkUfE5LbrRKt9g\"",
    "snippet":{
    "publishedAt":"2013-01-25T13:36:19.000Z",
    "channelId":"UCpVm7bg6pXKo1Pr6k5kxG9A",
    "title":"Weird Nature: Pink Dolphins?",
    "description":"Up to 9 feet long and weighing up to 300 pounds, pink river dolphins           are the largest freshwater dolphins in the world.",
    "thumbnails":{
        "default":{
           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZCJgvabihQ8/default.jpg"
        },
        "medium":{
           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZCJgvabihQ8/mqdefault.jpg"
        },
        "high":{
           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZCJgvabihQ8/hqdefault.jpg"
        }
    },
    "categoryId":"24"
    }
}
]
}
```

Is there anything I missed? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recordingDetails is not public for all videos, so if a video doesn't have these attributes available, nothing will be returned. By not returning anything, YouTube saves bandwidth and the response time can be faster.

---

Original reponse:

> This looks like a legitimate bug...
>
> recordingDetails is listed as an option on the videos resource
>   overview page, but not listed as a valid part in the video list method
>   here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
>
> Normally when you try using an invalid part you get a "400 Bad
>   Request" error, but recordingDetails still returns a 200 response, so
>   it looks like it really is supposed to be returned...
>
> You should submit a bug report here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have reported this issue at: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4051&thanks=4051&ts=1359472548

Comment: Actually, it looks like recordingDetails will only be returned if there are recordingDetails on the video... If there are no public recordingDetails, nothing is returned. Editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I was a little bit bad luck as I tried nearly 10 different vidoes several days ago and none of them returned recordingDetails. But I tried a video today and suddenly the recordingDetails appeared. Maybe it is better the API document can make this clear.

Comment: Now the issue has been fixed by YouTube, see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4051

Answer (score 0):

`recordingDetails` will only be returned for videos that explicitly have either the geolocation or the recording time set. 
(Not all videos set recording time; it's a distinct piece of metadata from publication time.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) call to retrieve a list of videos based on a `location` and `locationRadius`.

Then, with the returned list you can do a [videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) call including all video IDs in the `id` parameter of the query. You can then specify `recordingDetails` as "part" and it will work.

This is how Youtube does it here:

https://github.com/youtube/geo-search-tool