# How to access a video's recordingDetails (esp location) from YouTube Data API v3

Tags: geolocation, postman, youtube-data-api

Can successfully search API for list of videos within a certain radius of a latlong, but how do I access the latlong from the response data?

I've used both YouTube's API playground tool and Postman as well as run some sample code in VSCode. Here is what 1 entry in the response list of "items" looks like. Also, where's the URL to the video?

```
    {
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/fsqRXEIJN16lp5xdhifY88TcbVg\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "5QPeyrHwlwk"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2019-10-27T12:24:13.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCT350j4u6alUKyF9eu2bGug",
            "title": "Kincade Fire, PG&amp;E Power Shutoffs, Extreme winds across California | Live overnight coverage",
            "description": "Kincade Fire, PG&E Power Shutoffs, Extreme winds across California | Live overnight coverage 900000+ customers lose power due to PG&E public safety ...",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5QPeyrHwlwk/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5QPeyrHwlwk/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5QPeyrHwlwk/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "ABC10",
            "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
        }
    }
```

I would expect the response data to actually have the latitude and longitude, since I entered it into my query, but where is it? I've heard there's a property called 'recordingDetails' but how the heck do I get at it? I'm assuming this is just showing me the 'snippet' part, but is there another part I can query?

Comment: I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993066/youtube-api-v3-geolocation-information which seems to be working.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it for future reference.